# react-virtualized list component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized

Thanks in advance for the help. I am very new to react and am unable to wrap my head around this....

I am trying to use and create an infinite list using react-virtualized. Something like this: https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/List

I want to create my own list component [infiniteList] to which I can pass an array of objects as data and each list item is a separate component. So basically use react-virtualized list to create a custom list component that can be used

Comment: Have you looked at the react-virtualized docs? There are lots of examples of using `List` (like this one: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/List.md#examples). What you're describing sounds like a normal use. The source code for the demo you linked to is also available on GitHub, here: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/source/List/List.example.js

Comment: Hi @brianvaughn... I forked this plunker... https://plnkr.co/edit/gXyJds3zJvDl1ewNSqKh?p=preview .... If you notice I want to have the rowheights dynamic based on the row content. Could you help out? I tried the code from examples but it keeps giving me this error : "Uncaught Error: Invalid size returned for cell 0 of value undefined"

Comment: Read the docs? :) https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/CellMeasurer.md

Comment: Thanks for the pointers @brianvaughn... It really helped and I was able to implement it... Just had a couple of more questions :/

- I couldnt see any usage of cellMeasurer in this example from the repo.. How is the dynamic height being handled in this case? https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/source/List/List.example.js
- I tried adding padding for each row (via css) but I dont think thats being considered once the height is set.
- In case I wanted to click on a row and increase its height... how would I do that?

Comment: I tried your suggestions from other stackoverflow questions but keep getting _reactVirtualized.List.recomputeRowHeights is not a function and _reactVirtualized.List.forceUpdate is not a function

Comment: I think it would be useful to spend some reading through the official React docs, learning about things like refs and how they work. (You'll need to use refs in order to use methods like `recomputeRowHeights` or `forceUpdate`.) I hope the react-virtualized docs are pretty beginner-friendly as far as the API goes but they don't teach React basics. Those are super important to learn ahead of time! :)

Comment: Hi @brianvaughn Yes... the react-virtualized docs are very very good. Thanks for the pointers. The reason I was confused was I did not see those methods being used in the List example, so wanted to know how it was being handled.

Comment: @brianvaughn ... my bad... it does... sorry for the back and forth and thanks a bunch for the help.... But does that mean I cannot have a stateless component?

Comment: In other words is there a way to edit one single rows height without ref?

Comment: Nope. You need a ref in that case.